# Vertical table rows with fixed header and first column

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I'm currently trying to create a table with fixed 1st top row and fixed 1st left column.

There are plenty of solutions to this for a traditional table, but this table must be laid out with vertically stacked rows because of the way the data is going to be injected. The table columns (vertical rows) must also be able to overflow the parent and scroll.

At a minimum I would like the leftmost column fixed, the header (Loc 1, 2, 3 ) etc would be a nice to have.  I've tried this with a position:absolute but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<div style="postion:relative;">
<div class="table-responsive top-margin ">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr class="heads-col">
            <th>Data Decriptors</th>
            <th>Data Description 1</th>
            <th>Data Description 2</th>
            <th>Data Description 3</th>
            <th>Data Description 4</th>
            <th>Data Description 5</th>
            <th>Data Description 6</th>
            <th>Data Description 7</th>
            <th>Data Description 8</th>
            <th>Data Description 9</th>
            <th>Data Description 10</th>
            <th>Data Description 11</th>
            <th>Data Description 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Location 1</th>
            <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
            <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1xzb0x3s/3/

This solution was pretty much perfect: http://www.matts411.com/static/demos/grid/index.html

But I could not get it to work with vertical rows.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: That demo gives you the source use that.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: have a look at this: seems to suit your needs? http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/

Comment: Or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UqYgq/3/) *almost* works

Comment: MrCoder - I had looked at these, but it's getting them to work with vertical rows that is causing me issues. I need the header and <tds> to stack on top of one another both in the code and in the rendered table.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the cells in the leftmost column to "position:relative" and then update style.left with the scroll position of the container it will do the trick. I've added the class "fixed-row" and some JS, there's also a fiddle below.

```
var container = window.document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
var rowHeader = window.document.getElementsByClassName("fixed-row");
    for(var i=0; i<rowHeader.length; i++) {
        rowHeader[i].style.left = (container.scrollLeft + "px");
    }
}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/ftt64fxk/